# How to store Cookies for the next session in ReactJS for Sign-Up functionalities. Can anyone give me some idea?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookiestore

How to store Cookies for the next session in ReactJS for Sign-In functionalities. Can anyone give me some idea? Following is my ReactJs code for Sign-In page. Basically what I am trying to do is, a user can click the remember me box and that data should get store for the next time. Each time user don't have to enter the details after clicking the Remember Me box.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {SignUp} from "./SignUp";
import {ForgotPassword} from "./ForgotPassword";

export class SignIn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     fields: {},
     errors: {},
     remember_me: false
    }
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleValidation(){
    let fields = this.state.fields;
    let errors = {};
    let formIsValid = true;

    //Email
    if(!fields["email"]){
     formIsValid = false;
     errors["email"] = "Email ID is required";
    }

   //Password
   if(!fields["password"]){
      formIsValid = false;
      errors["password"] = "Password is required";
   }

   this.setState({errors: errors});
   return formIsValid;
 }

 onSubmit(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   if(this.state.fields["remember_me"]){
     var Cookies = this.state.fields;
     console.log(Cookies);
   }
  if(this.handleValidation()){
    var apiBaseUrl = "http://rediy-dev.railsfactory.com/";
    var input = this.state.fields;
    axios.post(apiBaseUrl+'/api/v1/sessions/login', input)
    .then(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
       if(response.data.status == 200){
         console.log("Login successful");
         alert("Login successful");
       }
       else if(response.data.status == 422){
         console.log("Invalid user details. Please enter again");
         alert("Invalid user details. Please enter again");
       }
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
     });
   }
  }

  onChange(field, e){
    let fields = this.state.fields;
    fields[field] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({fields});
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div id="login" className="form-popup" role="dialog">
        <div className="modal-dialog">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <form className="form-theme text-left">
              <div className="modal-header">
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h1 className="theme-title text-center">Sign In</h1>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <div className="form-group input">
                      <input
                        value={this.state.fields["email"]}
                        onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, "email")}
                        className="form-control input__field"
                        type="text"
                        id="unit"
                        refs="email"
                        placeholder="Email Id *"
                      />
                      <span style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.errors["email"]}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <div className="form-group input">
                      <input
                        value={this.state.fields["password"]}
                        onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, "password")}
                        className="form-control input__field"
                        type="text"
                        id="unit"
                        refs="password"
                        placeholder="Password *"
                      />
                      <span style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.errors["password"]}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-sm-6">
                    <div className="forgot-password">
                      <p> <Link to="/ForgotPassword">Forgot your password</Link></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-sm-6">
                    <div className="register">
                      <p>New User? <Link to="/SignUp">Register</Link></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <div className="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                      <input
                        refs="remember_me"
                        value={true}
                        onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, "remember_me")}
                        id="checkbox1"
                        type="checkbox" />
                      <label htmlFor="checkbox1">
                        Remember Me
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-footer">
                <div className="btn-wrap">
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-theme save btn btn-primary" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Sign In</button>
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-theme btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I recommend is that you use [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/). When you call an API on SignIn to log in also pass a `remember_me` boolean parameter to the backend and keep the session alive for that particular user. In response, the client-side will get an authentication token that can be used for further requests. Here is an example that can be useful in your case: [jwt authentication sample](https://github.com/auth0-blog/react-flux-jwt-authentication-sample/pull/31/files).